# Login with facebook in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, codeigniter

I am using this, for login with **Facebook**, but i am not getting user response here is the link

http://demos.idiotminds.com/link.php?link=https://www.box.com/s/108pspt0o0oj0fpr6ghf

I have tried this solution also for **codeigniter**

```
  protected function getCode() {
    $server_info = array_merge($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE);

    if (isset($server_info['code'])) {
        if ($this->state !== null &&
                isset($server_info['state']) &&
                $this->state === $server_info['state']) {

            // CSRF state has done its job, so clear it
            $this->state = null;
            $this->clearPersistentData('state');
            return $server_info['code'];
        } else {
            self::errorLog('CSRF state token does not match one provided.');
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

for log in with Facebook but i am not getting value from this `$user = $facebook->getUser();` it returns 0 value  even if i have logged into Facebook.
I have used so many codes for this but did not success, kindly help me out.
I am very frustrated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download PHP SDK for Facebook

Now create the a folder in application\libarires "facebook"

Put the "SRC" folder of PHP SDK

Now create a file with FacebookApp.php in that folder and put this code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once( APPPATH . 'libraries/facebook/src/facebook.php' );

class FacebookApp extends Facebook {

var $ci;

var $facebook;

var $scope;

public function __construct() {
  $this->ci =& get_instance();

  $this->facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => $this->ci->config-       >item('app_id'),'secret' => $this->ci->config->item('app_secret'), 'cookie' => true));

$this->scope = 'public_profile';
}

public function login_url() {
  $params = array('scope' => $this->scope);
  return $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}

public function logout_url() {
  return $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => base_url() .'logout'));
}

public function getFbObj(){
  return $this->facebook;
}

public function get_user() {
  $data = array();
  $data['fb_user'] = $this->facebook->getUser();
  if ($data['fb_user']) {
    try {
      $data['fb_user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
      return $data;
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $this->facebook->destroySession();
      $fb_login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $this->scope));
      redirect($fb_login_url, 'refresh'); 
    }
  }
}
```

Now in controller load this library
`$this->load->library('facebook/FacebookApp)`

in Method

`$obj_fb = new FacebookApp();
$fb_user_data = $obj_fb->get_user();
$data['fb_login_url'] = $obj_fb->login_url();`

put the fb_login_url in href of login button and now the login will done.

Hope it help you.

Comment: no libraries/facebook/src/facebook.php   facebook.php file in src folder  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0

Comment: Kindly give me coorect solution

Comment: https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk

downlload this and put SRC folder only

Comment: Hi, i am near to solution ,how can i get email of login user.if i echo $fb_user_data = $obj_fb->get_user();  .it is redirecting .I want to get email after login so that i can create session.

Comment: Add new scope `email` then only you will get email address

Comment: Loin work but its redirecting continuously and did not get the email. public function get_user() {
  $data = array();
  $data['fb_user'] = $this->facebook->getUser();
  if ($data['fb_user']) {
    try {
      $data['fb_user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me?scope=email');
      return $data;
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      $this->facebook->destroySession();
      $fb_login_url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => $this->scope));
      redirect($fb_login_url, 'refresh'); 
    }
  }
}  I have pass scope also

Comment: $obj_fb = new FacebookApp();
   $fb_user_data = $obj_fb->get_user();
   print_r($fb_user_data);
 //echo $user = $obj_fb->getUser();
  $data['fb_login_url'] = $obj_fb->login_url();   calling is like this.kindly give me correct solution

Comment: i have used the same code in 3 apps and it works fine now how can i figure you problem.

ranasoyab@gmail.com mail me the Zip of your code i will look at it

Comment: public function __construct() {
  $this->ci =& get_instance();

  $this->facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => $this->ci->config-       >item('app_id'),'secret' => $this->ci->config->item('app_secret'), 'cookie' => true));

$this->scope = 'public_profile, email';
}

not $this->facebook->api('/me?scope=email')

Comment: Hi ,its done thanks.but getting problem after login if i logout and facebook logout also but it makes cache ,i have to delete browser cookie then its variable seems to be free..how can i solve this problem..plz help me

Comment: on logout 
//Destory facebbok session
        $obj_fb = new FacebookApp();
        setcookie('fbs_'.$obj_fb->getFbObj()->getAppId(), '', time()-100, '/', 'localhost');
        $obj_fb->getFbObj()->destroySession();

        //Destory app session
        $this->session->unset_userdata('facebook_user_session');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();

then do 

$this->output->set_header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        $this->output->set_header("Pragma: no-cache");

Comment: Thanks dear i successfully done facebook login in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Rahul, I had a similar issue. You can find a pretty good solution [here](http://www.benmarshall.me/facebook-sdk-php-v4-codeigniter/).

If you still cannot figure the solution, why don't you look into the JavaScript [SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3). It is pretty straight forward and then use AJAX to act on the response that you get from Facebook.